# Higher Dimensional Derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I've seen the definition for higher dimension derivatives, like the derivative of scalars with respect to vectors, and vectors with respect to scalars, and scalars with respect to matrices, but I'm wondering if they have the same interpretation.

Namely, with something like the gradient and Hessian, do these first and second derivatives have the same limit definition as the classical derivative?

If this is the case, why are derivatives with respect to matrices defined as they are? Do they give a similar definition?

Comment: You would need to be more specific to get a proper answer, but generally the derivative is the 'best local approximation' in some defined sense (I am talking about the Fréchet derivative here). All of the combinations you mentioned can be expressed in the same way. Note that gradients & Hessians are only meaningful for scalar valued functions.

Answer (score 0):

The first derivative you would learn in multivariate calculus would be the "partial derivative."  The definition of the partial derivative is very similar to the definition from single-variable calculus.

Suppose you have a scalar function on three variables $f(x,y,z)$.  The partial derivative of f with respect to x would be defined as follows:

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \lim \limits_{h\to0} \frac{f(x+h,y,z) - f(x,y,z)}{h}$

The partial derivatives with respect to y and z would be defined similarly.  Operations such as the gradient, divergence, curl, etc. use these partial derivatives in different combinations.  Each has a different geometric interpretation.

For example the gradient: 
$\nabla f = (\frac{\partial f}{\partial x},\frac{\partial f}{\partial y},\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$)

The gradient points in the direction of maximum change of a function.  And over a surface, the gradient returns a vector that is perpendicular to the surface.